# Store an array in Web Storage using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, session-storage

I'd appreciate any hints, I need to write a code that uses Web Storage in such a way that `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(‘fruits’))[0].name` evaluates to ‘Banana’

How I understand this is that first I need to use `sessionStorage.setItem` to store an array and then the code above will get it. That’s what I managed to do so far (storing an object not an array)
`sessionStorage.setItem('fruits', JSON.stringify({ name: 'Banana' }))`

I also understand that it’s an array of fruits and I need to get the first element from it, but don’t know how to declare it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the object in square brackets, so it is in an array.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('fruits', JSON.stringify([{ name: 'Banana' }]))
```